# Call to undefined method Laravel\Passport\Passport::routes()

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I tried to use Laravel-passport so I installed this package in my project, but when i wanted to make route
i wrote this code in the AuthServiceProvider

```
 public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
   
        Passport::routes();
 
    }
```

When i run php artisan  route:list in the cmd i face with this error

- Call to undefined method Laravel\Passport\Passport::routes()

Comment: How did you import Laravel\Passport?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since version 11 passport's routes have been moved to a dedicated route file. You can remove the `Passport::routes()` call from your application's service provider.

If you dont want to use default passport routes. you can disabled the route in `register` method inside **AppServicerProvider**

```php
public function register()
{
   Passport::ignoreRoutes();
}
```

and you can copy the default passport routes from vendor `laravel\passport\routes\web.php`

for more detail about `UPGRADE` read this https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/11.x/UPGRADE.md

Answer (score 1):

Remove this comment on this line on your AuthServiceProvider file.

```
protected $policies = [
        'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];
```